# Multi-programmer programming IDE or plugin

Tags: c#, java, ide, extreme-programming

Are there any plugins/addons/website services which support good multi-programmer programming?

Just like Google Documents supports having people concurrently edit a document, is there any such similar features for IDEs? If so, Java and C# would be handier.

This feature would be useful for me to help others debug their code and help them see where they're going wrong, without actually having to be there with them.

I imagine this could also be useful for "pair programming" while at different locations (reduced usefulness I know, but still)

Thank you

Comment: I have often envisioned a essentially 'live' version of pastie.org, where you could be in with another person.  It would be very useful in helping others with small blocks of code.

Comment: I've heard from someone who has a friend at Google, they program this way... multiple people editing the code at the same time - so it definitely does exist!  I couldn't find on Google search what service they use... they probably wrote it themselves internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XPairtise](http://xpairtise.sourceforge.net/) is designed to assist with pair programming within Eclipse.

> This feature would be useful for me to help others debug their code and help them see where they're going wrong, without actually having to be there with them.

Often, desktop sharing (like GotoMeeting and similar) are easier for this, if this is your main goal.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't heard any buzz about it in awhile, but the [Eclipse Docshare plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin) is designed to do exactly this, in fact its underlying technology - Cola - [has a description directly addressing your idea of remote pair programming](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RT_Shared_Editing). [Video of the plugin in action](http://vimeo.com/1195398).

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is http://www.wave-vs.net/, I haven't used it but it seems exactly what you want.  Hopefully in the future more open-source variants of this will be developed for the [Wave protocol](http://www.waveprotocol.org/) allowing use with other languages.

Comment: wave-vs.net supports multi-driver distributed pair programming, multiple people working on same project item. Also support to share designers like winforms,aspx,html,wpf,wf and so on, so you can design with your pairs while coding, support for c#,f#,vb...